# Issues solving a Regression with numeric and categorical variables in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am very new to statistics and R in general so my question might be a bit dumb, but since I cannot find my solutions online I thought I should try ask it here.

I have a data frame `dataset` of a whole lot of different variables very similar to as follows:

```
 Item | Size   | Value    | Town
----------------------------------
A     |  10    |   800   | 1
B     |  11    |   100   | 2
A     |  17    |   900   | 2
D     |  13    |   200   | 3
B     |  15    |   500   | 1
C     |  12    |   250   | 3
E     |  14    |    NA   | 2
A     |        |   800   | 1
C     |        |   800   | 2
```

Basically, I have to try and 'guess' the Size based on the type of Item, it's Value, and the Town it was sold in, so I think a regression method would be a good idea.

I try and use a polynomial regression (although I'm not even sure if that's correct) to see how that looks by using a function similar to the following:

`summary(lm(Size~ polym(factor(Item), Value, factor(Town), degree=2, raw=TRUE), dataset))`

But I get this Warning message when I try to do this:

`Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(X, Y, ...) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors`

Can anyone tell me why this happens? More importantly, is what I've done even correct?

My second question is regarding `NA` values in a regression. In the dataset above, I have an `NA` value in the `Value` Column. From what I understand, R ignores rows which have an `NA` value in a column. But what if I have a lot of `NA` values? Also, it seems like a waste of data to automatically eliminate entire rows if there is only one `NA` value in a column, so I was wondering if there is perhaps a better way of solving or working around this issue. Thanks!

EDIT: I just have one more question: In the regression model I have created it appears there are new 'levels' in the testing data which were not in the training data (e.g. the error says `factor(Town) has new levels`). What would be the right thing to do for cases such as this?

Comment: Remove the factors from `polym` - you are trying to square a factor variable which is not meaningful. First try `lm(Size ~ factor(Item) + factor(Town) + Value,...)` and then add a squared term of `Value` if needed.

Comment: @RemkoDuursma Ah thanks, I'll try that out now :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, follow @RemkoDuursma's suggestion in using `lm(Size ~ factor(Item) + factor(Town) + Value,...)` and look into other degrees as well (was there a reason why you chose squared?) by comparing residuals.

In regards to substituting NA values, you have many options:

1. substitute all with median variable value
2. substitute all with mean variable value
3. substitute each with prediction based on values of other variables

good luck, and next time you might want to check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/!

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll try to modify my data accordingly :) I just have one last question, if you have some free time would it be ok if you could check it out?

Comment: sure! check what out though, haha?

Comment: is it an error or a warning? the model should be able to predict based on the other variables instead (ie Value)

Comment: It's an error unfortunately, the full error is `Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action=na.action, xlev = object$xlevels): factor factor(Town) has new levels`. Is there a way to make it use predictions based on the other variables instead?

Comment: hmm...I would ask in crossvalidated (I posted the link in my answer), because my stats knowledge is also only developing right now aha